# How can I adjust the indentation of a verse environment?

Tags: indentation

I am interested in using the `verse` environment for a song book. There are many double columns (`{multicols}{2}`) and it is A5 paper, so in order to maximise the use of horizontal space on the page, I do not want the indentation on either side of the verse environment. Is it best to use the `verse` package?

Comment: If you want to adjust the indent only for some but not all verses, here is an approach that could be adapted: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281348/indent-block-within-verse-environment/281357#281357

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `verse` in `article` is, in full

```
\newenvironment{verse}
               {\let\\\@centercr
                \list{}{\itemsep      \z@
                        \itemindent   -1.5em%
                        \listparindent\itemindent
                        \rightmargin  \leftmargin
                        \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
```

so you could use

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{verse}
               {\let\\\@centercr
                \list{}{\itemsep      \z@
                        \itemindent   -1.5em%
                        \listparindent\itemindent
                        \rightmargin  \leftmargin
                        \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}%
                \item\relax}
               {\endlist}
\makeatother
```

and change the two instances of `1.5em` to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks. Now I want to change the inter-paragraph spacing. I'm guessing it's to do with `\itemsep`. What does `\z@` do?

Comment: @ahorn: See [What does `\z@` do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55400/5764)

Comment: @ahorn If you refer to spacing between stanzas within a `verse` environment and are using the `reledmac` package, then this question can help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302770/how-can-i-set-a-skip-between-stanzas

Comment: I decided to use the `verse` package. Where did you find the definition of `verse`? I want to look up the definition of other environments. I think `quote` is defined in TeX, because I cannot find it in source2e.pdf.

Comment: @ahorn as I said, in article.cls `quote`  is in the same place and even simpler `\newenvironment{quote}
               {\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin}\item\relax}
               {\endlist}`

Comment: Whenever I try to use your \renewenvironment{verse} code, I get an error when I call verse with the optional verse parameter as in:

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

Any thoughts?

Comment: @RosesBouquet the verse enviornment in article class and this answer have no optional argument